# Drop indexes separately from drop table?

Tags: firebird

Firebird: With large tables with many indexes (primary and secondary), will separately dropping the indexes before the DROP TABLE, be faster then just letting Firebird remove the indexes at the DROP TABLE?

Comment: Have you tried it? I suspect that it doesn't make a difference as the server will execute the same actions, except that one is a single command and the other requires you to execute separate commands (which has its own overhead, like network roundtripping etc).

Comment: Right now my tables are not that large that I can see a difference, but several of our clients will have humongous tables. The DROPs will occur in a database update scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there should be a big difference! 
dropping the indexes should be instantaneous and dropping the table too!

Comment: Data definition language is not logged. that is the reason it should be instantaneous. Some exotic databases have logged DDL but I don't think firebird is one of those.

Comment: The only actions done are removing the entries in system tables from tables and indexes and space allocation.

Comment: I did some Googling and this post made me worry a little: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/firebird-support/message/114995
I know that e.g. SQL Server uses deferred drop for large tables, but I have no idea about FireBird.

Comment: @JanDoggen What is the use case? Dropping tables is usually part of an update process, does it really matter if it takes a while to drop a table? If it is part of your normal application logic, you might want to look at global temporary tables instead.

Comment: dropping and recreating tables is usually a use case for a fast bulk delete. normally you also have the truncate which is also categorised as DDL but only drops the storage.